# Can I restore a Windows 7 backup made in 32 bit after installing Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, windows-home-server, windows-backup

I'm a Mac user helping out a friend, so I don't know much about Windows. They have a Windows Home Server that their PC backs up to. The docs for Windows 7 64 bit say that it needs to be a clean install, and that you have to restore user files after installing. Is the WHS backup (created by a 32-bit OS) sufficient to restore from? Or do I need to somehow manually copy their documents, programs, etc. to a backup drive before wiping?

Comment: Host OS that makes the backup typically does not matter, you might edit your question to include more details as to what the backup software is that was used to make the backup and what type of backup it was, ie, system image or file backup. Also are you upgrading the OS on the PC? We need more details.

Comment: do you want a copmlete Restore or Just the Preferences and Setting and your data ?